# How to confirm results from “find_element_by” search using Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, chromium

I'm trying to automate login to https://auth.tesla.com/login but getting stuck trying to enter my email address.

I've tried these Python code lines:
`email_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[1]")`
or `email_box = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Email')`
followed `email_box.clear()'`

But I'm getting an error `Element must be user-editable in order to clear it` Which suggests I haven’t found the right element. My questions:
Is there a way to determine just which html element was found by the `find_element_by` code?
Or perhaps is there a better way to find the email box and enter my email address into?
(I'm doing this with Raspbian Buster using Selenium 3.141.0 and Chromium 74.0.3729.157). Thanks!

Comment: If `email_box` is a `form` element, that's probably why you are getting the error message. There might be an `input` element you should try locating instead -- these are usually `user-editable`. If you post the HTML for the `email_box` you are trying to locate, we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you like to visualize the selected element on the page, after selecting you can apply some JS on it, so that you can see which element you got (debug purpose)

   email_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[1]")
   driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("style", "color: red; border: 2px solid red;")', email_box)
2. `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Email')`: this is wrong because there is no LINK (LINK element is an < a > element) with text 'email' on this page . Also you can't clear < a > elements. Usually `clear` is applied at inputs.
3. `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[1]")`: this is wrong because here you get the first < form > element on the page. Again forms can't be cleared.
4. What you are looking is: css selector:

   form#login-form input[placeholder='Email']

Or xpath

```
//form[@id='login-form']//input[@placeholder='Email']
```

5. Also when you open the page in chrome browser, and you open developer tools (F12), go to elements tab; open search (click ctr + F) you can paste there your xpath/css selector, and see which element is selected

Answer (score 0):

Your code line email_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[1]") finds the form, not input fields. You can check that using WebElement attributes and methods:

- get_attribute(name) (The value for the element’s name attribute)
- text (The text within the element, such as 'hello' in hello)

Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

email_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[1]")
print(email_box.text)
```

Output:

```
'Sign In\nI forgot my password\nSIGN IN\nCreate an account'
```

So that is what Your browser.find_element_by_xpath("//form[1]") found.

There are many ways to reach this email field and test it.

If You are sure, that web-page will remain same, You can use XPATH for that input field:

```
 xp='/html/body/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/input'
 email_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xp)
 email_box.send_keys('Test')
```

Another way is by collecting all inputs and identifying them. This is more for knowing what is what, than finding and using email field directly. :

```
input_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("input")
for field in input_list:
    print(input_list.index(i), i.get_attribute('placeholder'))
```

Output:

```
0 Username
1 Email
2 Password
```

So now You know that there are 3 input fields and second one is email and after that goes password. Assuming that page will remain the same You can now fill them with text:

```
input_list[1].send_keys('email@email.com')
input_list[2].send_keys('Secret_password')
```

You can also write something Yourself in the input and try to detect value (Test is already in from previous code):

```
 xp='/html/body/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/input'
 email_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xp)
 email_box.get_attribute('value')
```